# How to get the year wise employee as per the promotion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get the year wise employee as per the promotion.

**Example:**
Employee Number 'A-001' Join on '01-07-2013' then the O/P will be showing in image.

As Employee Number 'A-001' there is no promotion in 2014 then in Last_Designation,Promoted_Designation, Last_Gross and Promoted_Gross
 need to be same as 2013 or previous one.

Below is my SQL Query with Data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Emp_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Emp_Number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Emp_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Emp_JoiningDate] [date] NULL,
    [Emp_ResignDate] [date] NULL,
    [Emp_Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Emp_CurrentDesignation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Emp_CurrentGross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Employee]
           ([Emp_No]
           ,[Emp_Number]
           ,[Emp_Name]
           ,[Emp_JoiningDate]
           ,[Emp_ResignDate]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_CurrentDesignation]
           ,[Emp_CurrentGross])
     VALUES
           (1,'A-001','Alex','2012-07-01',null,'On Board','Trainee3',2000)
GO

INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Employee]
           ([Emp_No]
           ,[Emp_Number]
           ,[Emp_Name]
           ,[Emp_JoiningDate]
           ,[Emp_ResignDate]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_CurrentDesignation]
           ,[Emp_CurrentGross])
     VALUES
           (2,'A-002','Smith','2014-07-01','2015-07-01','Resigned','HR1',1500)
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Promotion](
    [Prom_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Prom_EmpNo] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Last_Designation] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Promoted_Designation] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [WEF_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Promoted_Gross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Last_Gross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Promotion]
           ([Prom_No]
           ,[Prom_EmpNo]
           ,[Last_Designation]
           ,[Promoted_Designation]
           ,[WEF_Date]
           ,[Promoted_Gross]
           ,[Last_Gross])
     VALUES
           (1,1,'Trainee1','Trainee2','2013-11-01',1000,500)
GO


INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Promotion]
           ([Prom_No]
           ,[Prom_EmpNo]
           ,[Last_Designation]
           ,[Promoted_Designation]
           ,[WEF_Date]
           ,[Promoted_Gross]
           ,[Last_Gross])
     VALUES
           (2,1,'Trainee2','Trainee3','2015-03-01',2000,1000)
GO
```

[image: Ooutput result]

Comment: please show your expected result for the sample data provided

Comment: The expected result shown in attached image.

Comment: Where does you first column `Year` in result comes from?

Comment: The year column come from Emp_JoiningDate

Comment: Why `Smith` which join in 2014 appear under 2013 ? And what if there are more than 1 promotion within a year ?

Comment: sorry i was copy paste, smith need to remove from 2013, in year if promotion more than one then shows the latest one

Comment: smith need to be put upto 2015 becoz he resigned in 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my script with various sample data and let me know if it not working any particular sample data.

> First you can create and populate one year table which can be
>   permanent .In my example it is temporary.

```
create table #Year(yr int primary key)
insert into #Year
select (ROW_NUMBER()over(order by number)+1900) from master..spt_values
--select * from #Year
```

Main query start from here.

```
      ;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT Emp_No NewEmpNo
        ,min(year(emp_joiningdate)) minYear
        ,max(year(case when Emp_ResignDate is not null then Emp_ResignDate else getdate() END)) maxYear
    FROM [dbo].[Employee]
    GROUP BY Emp_No
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT c.yr
        ,p.NewEmpNo
       ,e.*
    FROM cte p
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT yr
        FROM #Year c
        WHERE c.yr >= minYear
            AND c.yr <= maxYear
        ) c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT e.*
            ,p.*
            ,year(isnull(p.WEF_Date,e.Emp_JoiningDate)) PYr
        FROM dbo.employee E
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Promotion] P ON e.Emp_No = p.Prom_EmpNo
        ) e ON p.NewEmpNo = e.Emp_No
        AND c.yr = e.pyr
    )

--select * from CTE1    
,CTE2 as
(
SELECT yr
    ,NewEmpNo
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Number, prv.Emp_Number) Emp_Number
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Name, prv.Emp_Name) Emp_Name
    ,isnull(c.Emp_JoiningDate, prv.Emp_JoiningDate) Emp_JoiningDate
    ,isnull(c.Emp_ResignDate, prv.Emp_ResignDate) Emp_ResignDate
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Status, prv.Emp_Status) Emp_Status
    ,isnull(c.Emp_CurrentDesignation, prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Emp_CurrentDesignation
    ,isnull(c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Emp_CurrentGross
    ,COALESCE(c.Last_Designation, prv.Last_Designation
    ,c.Emp_CurrentDesignation,prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Last_Designation
    ,COALESCE(c.Promoted_Designation, prv.Promoted_Designation
    ,c.Emp_CurrentDesignation,prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Promoted_Designation
    ,COALESCE(c.Last_Gross, prv.Last_Gross
    ,c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Last_Gross
    ,COALESCE(c.Promoted_Gross, prv.Promoted_Gross
    ,c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Promoted_Gross
     ,prv. PYr
     --,prv1.*
FROM cte1 c
outer APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 prve.*
        ,prvp.*
        ,year(isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate))Pyr

    FROM dbo.employee prve
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Promotion] prvp ON prve.Emp_No = prvp.Prom_EmpNo
    WHERE   (c.yr >= year(isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate)) 
    ) 

        AND c.NewEmpNo = prve.Emp_No
    ORDER BY  isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate)  DESC

    ) prv

    )

    select 

    yr
    ,NewEmpNo
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Number, prv.Emp_Number) Emp_Number
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Name, prv.Emp_Name) Emp_Name
    ,isnull(c.Emp_JoiningDate, prv.Emp_JoiningDate) Emp_JoiningDate
    ,isnull(c.Emp_ResignDate, prv.Emp_ResignDate) Emp_ResignDate
    ,isnull(c.Emp_Status, prv.Emp_Status) Emp_Status
    ,isnull(c.Emp_CurrentDesignation, prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Emp_CurrentDesignation
    ,isnull(c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Emp_CurrentGross
    ,COALESCE(c.Last_Designation, prv.Last_Designation
    ,c.Emp_CurrentDesignation,prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Last_Designation
    ,COALESCE(c.Promoted_Designation, prv.Promoted_Designation
    ,c.Emp_CurrentDesignation,prv.Emp_CurrentDesignation) Promoted_Designation
    ,COALESCE(c.Last_Gross, prv.Last_Gross
    ,c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Last_Gross
    ,COALESCE(c.Promoted_Gross, prv.Promoted_Gross
    ,c.Emp_CurrentGross, prv.Emp_CurrentGross) Promoted_Gross
     ,prv. PYr

    from cte2 c
    outer apply(
    SELECT TOP 1 prve.*
        ,prvp.*
        ,year(isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate))Pyr

    FROM dbo.employee prve
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Promotion] prvp ON prve.Emp_No = prvp.Prom_EmpNo
    WHERE   (c.yr <= year(isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate)) 
    ) 

        AND c.NewEmpNo = prve.Emp_No
    ORDER BY  isnull(WEF_Date,Emp_JoiningDate)  
    )prv
    ORDER BY yr

DROP TABLE #Year
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Employee Join on '2012-07-01' then year start from 2012 to current year which is 2017, with your query start from 2013.

Comment: @user3069097,check my latest.it will go till 2017 for each emp.but it start with min year of date in promotion table.

Comment: Many Thanks. But the employee join on 2012 it must show from 2012, if there is no data in promotion table for 2012 then check for next year data, same as if 2014 there is no data then enter 2013 data. Many thanks

Comment: @user3069097 , Sorry,i misunderstood your requirement.In my example Emp 1 join on 2013 and hasn't resgin so it data is from 2013 till 2017.Emp 2 join on 2014 and resign on 2015 so it data is from 2014 to 2015.Why EMP2 start from 2013 as mention in your image ?you explain this then i try to correct my query.

Comment: I will send you once again all my query and data

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
 [Emp_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Emp_Number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Emp_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Emp_JoiningDate] [date] NULL,
 [Emp_ResignDate] [date] NULL,
 [Emp_Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Emp_CurrentDesignation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Emp_CurrentGross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Employee]
           ([Emp_No]
           ,[Emp_Number]
           ,[Emp_Name]
           ,[Emp_JoiningDate]
           ,[Emp_ResignDate]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_CurrentDesignation]
           ,[Emp_CurrentGross])
     VALUES
           (1,'A-001','Alex','2012-07-01',null,'On Board','Trainee3',2000)
GO

Comment: INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Employee]
           ([Emp_No]
           ,[Emp_Number]
           ,[Emp_Name]
           ,[Emp_JoiningDate]
           ,[Emp_ResignDate]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_CurrentDesignation]
           ,[Emp_CurrentGross])
     VALUES
           (2,'A-002','Smith','2014-07-01','2015-07-01','Resigned','HR1',1500)
GO

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Promotion](
 [Prom_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Prom_EmpNo] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Last_Designation] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 [Promoted_Designation] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 [WEF_Date] [date] NULL,
 [Promoted_Gross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Last_Gross] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Promotion]
           ([Prom_No]
           ,[Prom_EmpNo]
           ,[Last_Designation]
           ,[Promoted_Designation]
           ,[WEF_Date]
           ,[Promoted_Gross]
           ,[Last_Gross])
     VALUES
           (1,1,'Trainee1','Trainee2','2013-11-01',1000,500)
GO

Comment: INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Promotion]
           ([Prom_No]
           ,[Prom_EmpNo]
           ,[Last_Designation]
           ,[Promoted_Designation]
           ,[WEF_Date]
           ,[Promoted_Gross]
           ,[Last_Gross])
     VALUES
           (2,1,'Trainee2','Trainee3','2015-03-01',2000,1000)
GO

Comment: First it should check the Year based on Emp_JoiningDate and according check the last_designation,promoted_designation, last_gross and promoted gross based on promotion table, if data is not available then enter the data as previous or next year. example 2012 and 2013 there  is no promotion then enter 2014 data on 2012 and 2013

Comment: i already update result and sql structure and query in question

Comment: Many Thanks. But this is not exactly same as attached image result.

Comment: Many Thanks, but 2012 showing all the null value, In 2012 result should show as 2013. Thanks Basit

Comment: Many Many Thanks, Take a look of query showing not correct result. INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Employee]
           ([Emp_No]
           ,[Emp_Number]
           ,[Emp_Name]
           ,[Emp_JoiningDate]
           ,[Emp_ResignDate]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_CurrentDesignation]
           ,[Emp_CurrentGross])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'A-001'
           ,'Alex'
           ,'2013-02-25'
           ,null
           ,'On Board'
           ,'Trainee2'
           ,1000)
GO

Comment: promotion data is INSERT INTO [UserDB].[dbo].[Promotion]
           ([Prom_No]
           ,[Prom_EmpNo]
           ,[Last_Designation]
           ,[Promoted_Designation]
           ,[WEF_Date]
           ,[Promoted_Gross]
           ,[Last_Gross])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,1
           ,'Trainee1'
           ,'Trainee2'
           ,'2017-04-01'
           ,1000
           ,500)
GO

Comment: In above example Employee Promoted on 2017, but with this query showing from 2013 to 2017 promoted designation are same

Comment: in above example,employee is not promoted on 2017,emp 1 is promoted on 2015 to Trainee3 and from 2015 to 2017 promoted designation is showing Trainee3  which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `CTE [Year]` is to get the list of years from the `Emp_JoiningDate` and `ResignDate`. After that just `CROSS join` to the `Employee` table

For the promotion information (prev and promoted), use `OUTER APPLY` to get the last row by `WEF_Date`

```
; with 
[Year] as
(
    select  [Year]      = min(datepart(year, e.Emp_JoiningDate))
    from    [Employee] e

    union all

    select  [Year]      = y.[Year] + 1
    from    [Year] y
    where   [Year]  < datepart(year, getdate())
)
select  y.[Year], e.Emp_No, e.Emp_Number, e.Emp_Name, e.Emp_JoiningDate,
        e.Emp_ResignDate, e.Emp_Status, 
        e.Emp_CurrentDesignation, e.Emp_CurrentGross,
        Last_Designation    = coalesce(p.Last_Designation, e.Emp_CurrentDesignation),
        Promoted_Designation= coalesce(p.Promoted_Designation, e.Emp_CurrentDesignation),
        Last_Gross      = coalesce(p.Last_Gross, e.Emp_CurrentGross),
        Promoted_Gross  = coalesce(p.Promoted_Gross, e.Emp_CurrentGross)
from    [Employee] e
        cross join [Year] y
        outer apply
        (
            select  top 1 *
            from    [Promotion] x
            where   x.Prom_EmpNo    = e.Emp_No
            and datepart(year, x.[WEF_Date])    <= y.[Year]
            order by x.WEF_Date desc
        ) p
where   y.[Year]    >= datepart(year, e.Emp_JoiningDate)
and y.[Year]    <= datepart(year, isnull(e.Emp_ResignDate, getdate()))
order by y.[Year], e.Emp_No
```

RESULT

```
2013    1   A-001   Alex    2013-07-01  NULL        On Board    Trainee3    2000    Trainee1    Trainee2    500 1000
2014    1   A-001   Alex    2013-07-01  NULL        On Board    Trainee3    2000    Trainee1    Trainee2    500 1000
2014    2   A-002   Smith   2014-07-01  2015-07-01  Resigned    HR1     1500    HR1     HR1     1500    1500
2015    1   A-001   Alex    2013-07-01  NULL        On Board    Trainee3    2000    Trainee2    Trainee3    1000    2000
2015    2   A-002   Smith   2014-07-01  2015-07-01  Resigned    HR1     1500    HR1     HR1     1500    1500
2016    1   A-001   Alex    2013-07-01  NULL        On Board    Trainee3    2000    Trainee2    Trainee3    1000    2000
2017    1   A-001   Alex    2013-07-01  NULL        On Board    Trainee3    2000    Trainee2    Trainee3    1000    2000
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks, Just change the date of Joining of Employee A-001 to 2012-07-01 then 2012 getting the latest Gross and Latest promotion, it should take the 2013 gross in last&promoted designation and gross.